# How can you set an entry point to a folder in a node package?

Tags: node.js, program-entry-point

I work on a component library and a React app that makes use of that component library. My component library looks like this when I `build` it:

```
/core
  /components
    /MyComponent
  /utils
  /hooks
```

This means when we import a component, it looks like this:

```
import '@our-package/core/components/MyComponent/MyComponent';
```

Is there a way we can make the `components` folder our entry point? The `utils` and `hooks` folders should not be accessible. Ideally, we could use:

```
import `@our-package/core/MyComponent/MyComponent`
```

I'm reading about the node `main` property you can use in `package.json` but it doesn't look like it works with folders. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could move your folder upwards, in the same directory as your `package.json`.

If you're targeting a newer version of Node.js, you can also make use of the new [packages structure](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#). You can basically say exactly where `@our-package/core/subpath` points at in your `@our-package/core` package. It has a whole system behind it that should allow you to export whole directories at certain subpaths.